# JavaEE application throws HTTP 408 when debugging application with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

currently I'm starting to learn JavaEE. I created a simple donation-management-system which is secured by a login form. In the past I've just deployed my code to JBoss AS 7.1.1 and accessed it via browser.

However I would like to debug my application using Eclipse, as my application is starting to get bigger. I found several tutorials on the web and here at so but they didn't bring the expected result.

Here is what I did: 
I edited the "standalone.conf.bat" and uncommented the line

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Then I created a new "Remote Java Application"-Configuration in Eclipse using localhost as hostname and 8787 as port.

Now my problem is as follows: 
When I try to debug the application, the integrated eclipse browser opens up and show the expected web page, but when I enter the credentials and click "Login" I this exception:

```
HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser
```

When I open my application in f.e. Firefox everything works fine.

Any ideas how to fix that? I'm already getting grey hair..

**Edit: For the Login-Form I use the j_security_check**

Comment: Why bother using integrated browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could potentially be an issue with the integrated browser in Eclipse. Perhaps it's not handling session cookies properly.

To eliminate that possibility, I believe that in your general Eclipse preferences you can change the "Web Browser" setting to an external web browser (like Firefox) and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: Thanks, could have thought about that on my own ;-)